# Save related Images Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this basic model layout:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class ListingImage(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=listing_image_path)
```

Im trying to write a serializer which lets me add an rest api endpoint for creating Listings including images.

My idea would be this:

```
class ListingImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ListingImage
        fields = ('image',)

class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ListingImageSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Listing
    fields = ('name', 'images')

def create(self, validated_data):
    images_data = validated_data.pop('images')
    listing = Listing.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for image_data in images_data:
        ListingImage.objects.create(listing=listing, **image_data)

    return listing
```

My Problems are:

1. I'm not sure how and if I can send a list of images in a nested dictionary using a multipart POST request.
2. If I just post an images list and try to convert it from a list to a list of dictionaries before calling the serializer, I get weird OS errors when parsing the actual image.

   ```
   for key, item in request.data.items():
       if key.startswith('images'):
           # images.append({'image': item})
           request.data[key] = {'image': item}
   ```

My request code looks like this:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder

api_token = 'xxxx'

images_data = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={
        'name': 'test',
        'images[0]': (open('lilo.png', 'rb'), 'image/png'),
        'images[1]': (open('panda.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')
    }
)


response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/listings/', data=images_data,
                         headers={
                             'Content-Type': images_data.content_type,
                             'Authorization': 'Token' + ' ' + api_token
                         })
```

I did find a very hacky solution which I will post in the answers but its not really robust and there needs to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my solution is based off of this post and works quite well but seems very unrobust and hacky.

I change the images field from a relation serializer requiring a dictonary to a ListField. Doing this i need to override the list field method to actually create a List out of the RelatedModelManager when calling "to_repesentation".

This baiscally behaves like a list on input, but like a modelfield on read.

```
class ModelListField(serializers.ListField):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        """
        List of object instances -> List of dicts of primitive datatypes.
        """
        return [self.child.to_representation(item) if item is not None else None for item in data.all()]


class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ModelListField(child=serializers.FileField(max_length=100000, allow_empty_file=False, use_url=False))

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ('name', 'images')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        images_data = validated_data.pop('images')
        listing = Listing.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for image_data in images_data:
            ListingImage.objects.create(listing=listing, image=image_data)

        return listing
```

Comment: Is this part of your question or are you (immediately) answering your own question?

Comment: as I stated at the end of the question: "I did find a very hacky solution which I will post in the answers but its not really robust and there needs to be a better way to do this." 
Im just providing this because it works and I want to save ppls time when trying to help.

Comment: Hey, man. I have tried you solution, but it does not seem to work for me. I get the following error: 'Image' object has no attribute 'all'
Any ideas?